# How to have an Entity Framework (EF6) dynamic association to latest entry?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-model-first

I have this table/entity scenario in my model-first EF project (simplified):

```
Machine:
  ID (primary key)
  GroupId (string)
  ActiveConfiguration (of type Configuration)

Configuration:
  ID (primary key)
  GroupId (string)
  ValidFrom (date)
```

Now what I need to achieve is an association such, that *Machine.ActiveConfiguration* will contain latest configuration of a given *GroupId*.

Example (data):

```
Configuration (ID = '1', GroupId = 'A', ValidFrom = '01/01/2017')
Configuration (ID = '2', GroupId = 'B', ValidFrom = '01/01/2017')
Configuration (ID = '3', GroupId = 'A', ValidFrom = '01/01/2018')
```

When *Machine* entity is selected at (for example) **6/30/2017** its *ActiveConfiguration* property should contain *Configuration* (ID = '**1**'). When selected at **6/30/2018** it should contain *Configuration* (ID = '**3**').

Is this possible somehow?

Comment: There is no way to define this sort of association. What you want to do is write a query that does what you want, and wrap it inside your `ActiveConfiguration` property.

Comment: That's unfortunate, but it was kinda expected. Thanks.